# Best way to fix a wood siding corner that's missing a piece?

Tags: wood, siding

On the corner of my siding, I have a missing piece of wood, and there is an orange filling showing up.

[image]

I bought a 2x4 and I want to cover that missing piece, but cutting to fit. However, I have a couple of questions:

1. What is this orange thing showing and is it okay to remove/replace it?
2. What is the best way to attach the new 2x4 piece to the existing corner?

Update:

I've removed the orange substance and noticed there was a black layer right under it, that also got removed. So, my question is what type of layer/substance I should put before putting the 2x4?

[image]

Comment: It appears to be glue. Prefered: For the fix remove the old piece and add a new one. Alternate: You could just add a short piece, fill the gap and paint it to match.

Comment: Gil, what would be the best way to attach the short piece to the existing one?

Comment: Is the orange an underlying thick layer now revealed, like perhaps insulation, or is it just smeared on the surface? What kind of weather/wetness exposure does this corner get? You will want to make sure water cannot get behind your new piece and into the structure or the unprotected ends of the adjacent siding boards.

Comment: After you clean it up I would try contractor's glue. You could also add a screw or two to hold it in place (probably #6 x3.5") but before doing that be sure you can get into some wood before you put the replacement back. At that point you will know how long the screw has to be.

Comment: Hey folks - I've updated with a new picture, after removing the orange thingy. I think it was insulation, as Armand said. This corner doesn't get a lot of sun, so it will be pretty wet/moist. What should I put in there to protect it from the weather? I don't know what the orange thing is called.

Comment: That wasn't insulation - it's far too thin.  It looks like some sort of foaming glue to me.  For insulation to be any use it has to be multiple inches thick (but foaming glue may seal gaps and provide draft-proofing - which is very, very, important for insulating.).

Comment: Got it! I will use foaming glue again.

Comment: The black layer was probably tar paper or its equivalent.  You'll want to put some between that exposed wood sheathing and your new wood section.  I'd prime your new wood piece on all sides before installing it, and use nails or screws to fasten it to the underlying sheathing. Use caulk/orange stuff first to make sure no water can get into those exposed wood ends when the repair piece is in place.

Comment: What's the oblong whitish thing in the middle of the exposed sheathing? Is it wiring?

Comment: Armand, no, it was some remaining plastic thingy. Not wiring.